# Batch read on DynamoDB or stream data to S3

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-dynamodb, aws-lambda, amazon-kinesis

I have a dynamodb table, that I need to read hourly to execute a load on datawarehouse. I am thinkin in two options:

1. Create a job that scan table filtering by last_update timestamp  and load to DW.
2. Using a Kinesis + Lambda to every new update/insert I dump the records to S3, for further processing. Then I create a hourly job that load the s3 file to DW.

What is the best approach?

Answer (score 1):

For number 1, your way is pretty okay. 
I need more specifications in order to improve.

For number 2, you should use Kinesis Firehose and configure it to save data directly to S3.

Answer (score 1):

Using DynamoDB Updates Stream is an efficient way to connect between your front end serving database (DynamoDB) and your analytical database. It allows decoupling that gives independence to each part of your system to evolve without ruining the other part.

It also allows you to have a serverless environment that reduces your operational load and efforts. You can with a single Lambda function that is reading the update stream to decide which data will be logged to which datastore. Usually people are writing all the inserts/updates/deletes to S3 as a log, and the relevant records and columns to the various tables in the data warehouse (for example, Redshift). Your Lambda function can put the transformed records to a couple of Kinesis Firehose that will move the data reliably to their destinations.

Comment: Great @Guy! And how dynamodb stream handles when the lambda function fails? Does it retry?

Comment: Yes, it will retry. But the question is why did the Lambda failed. If you have a  bug in your code or a "poison pill" (a records that is killing your function), it will fail forever until the changes are deleted from the stream (24 hours).

Comment: Thanks @Guy.
Another question: Imagine that I have old record before I activate the (stream + lambda). Is it possible to reprocess it? i.e. put it on the stream as if it was a new record.

Comment: No. Only updates after the stream being activated will appear there. If you want to process old data you can run a backup (with EMR or Scan) and process these records.